# How to avoid R converting F to False when converting logical vector to character

Tags: r

I've imported some data from my participants where some of my variables are F/M (female/male) and when I import it, R converts vectors with only F into a logical vector. When I then convert them back to character, the F has been transformed into FALSE. How can I avoid this F to FALSE transformation?

I know I could just transform all the FALSE back into F but I'd like to find an alternative solution to avoid my code looking cluttered.

This is my code for now and I suspect the issue is within `lapply`. I can't really give a full set of data since the command is incorporated into reading the csv files. I've give an example of a sample of what the data looks like in the CSV file vs. how it looks like when R has converted it. The actual data set has many more columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)

csv_data <- data.frame(first = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                first_sex = c("F", "F", "F", "F"),
                second = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
                second_sex = c("M", "F", "F", "F"))

R_output_data <- data.frame(first = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                            first_sex = c(F, F, F, F),
                            second = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
                            second_sex = c("M", "F", "F", "F"))

files <- list.files(path = "path to data", 
                    pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)

test_data <- lapply(files, read_csv) %>% 
  lapply(.,mutate_if, is.logical, as.character) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

Comment: `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`  in your `read.(csv/tsv/table)` call? Test with `csv_data %>% 
  map(.,class)`

Comment: Please try `as.is` of `read.csv` to avoid conversion

Comment: `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` isn't a `read_csv` option. `col_types =  ...` should work though.

Comment: You could read all columns in as character and convert them later. It may be flexible to read all in as character, change "f" and "m" to "female" and "male", and then change column types using `type_convert` or something similar. To read everything in as character using `read_csv`, add `col_types = cols(.default = "c")`.

Comment: Could you add what code was used to import your data?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. I've now added that I'm using tidyverse and that this is just a small sample of each participant's data. The real data sets are much bigger but the issue is the same none the less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that the problematic columns are `first_sex` and `second_sex`, you can use the `col_*` handlers from `readr`. For example:

```
require(readr)    
notlogical<-cols(first_sex=col_character(),second_sex=col_character())
#then in the lapply:
test_data <- lapply(files, read_csv, col_types=notlogical) #the rest is the same
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't feel very clean, but this type of process is what I was talking about in the comment. You do not need to specify specific column names (so it is somewhat flexible). But, if there are a couple columns causing the problem with the same names, that would be easier. Good luck!!

```
# Reading in all data as character using read_csv
test_data <- lapply(files, read_csv, col_types = cols(.default = "c"))

# using gsub to swap out f for female
test_data2 <- lapply(rapply(test_data, function(x) gsub("F|f", "Female", gsub("M|m", "Male", x)), 
how = "list"), as.data.frame, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Converting type for each dataframe in the list
final_data <- lapply(test_data2, type_convert)


# Checking if it worked
final_data[[1]]
  first first_sex second second_sex
1     1    Female      2       Male
2     1    Female      2     Female
3     1    Female      2     Female
4     1    Female      2     Female

sapply(final_data[[1]], class)
      first   first_sex      second  second_sex 
  "numeric" "character"   "numeric" "character"
```

**Data**

```
csv_data <- data.frame(first = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                       first_sex = c("F", "F", "F", "F"),
                       second = c(2, 2, 2, 2),
                       second_sex = c("M", "F", "F", "F"))


write_csv(csv_data, "csv_data.csv")
write_csv(csv_data, "csv2_data.csv")

files <- list.files(path = getwd(), 
                    pattern = "data.csv", full.names = T)
```

Comment: Yes the issue is luckily confined to a few columns so I've gone with an alternative approach, however this is great for when that is not the case. Thank you!

Comment: The simpler the better!